# Use API get data in Service Desk JIRA

Tags: python, api, jira

My Company is using JIRA.
And My task is need to use API get data in Service Desk.
Current we are exporting csv file from JIRA. and we want to improve use api get data instead of export file csv.
Some Field im csv file is " Summary, Issue key, Issue id, Issue Type, Status, Priority, Resolution, Assignee, Reporter, Creator, Created, Updated, Last Viewed, Resolved, Comment ..... "
I have learned about jira's api ,
Ex : /rest/servicedeskapi/request.
It only retrieves requests made by the user or assigned to the user (Ex user is me).
I need to get all the requests in that project.
I need to your help with api ( python ) get data in Service Desk Jira.
Thanks All.

Comment: This is a broad question. Try to google on how to access webapis using python. Later if you are stuck somewhere, post it with all the details.

Comment: @ChandraEskay , I understand , But I want to know someone who did it. so I can give advice on how to do it or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The API should return all the requests the user making the request has access to. Are you able to view all the requests when you log in through the JIRA UI? If the permissions are set up to restrict your account from viewing all the requests, you won't be able to access those tickets via the API. Make sure your account is a Project Administrator for the Service Desk project you're working in, and if it's not have your account added to that role.